# How do I write audio data at a certain sample rate?

Tags: c, frequency

I am making a synthesizer by piping data into aplay (I know it's not ideal) and the sound is lagging behind the keypresses which alter the sound. I believe this is because aplay is going at a constant 8000 Hz, but the c program is going at an unstable rate. How do I get the for loop to go at 8000 Hz in C?

Comment: This question is far too broad. There is no simple measure to ensure this. It depends on the target platform, available libraries, etc.

Comment: You might have more success using an API like ALSA, PulseAudio, etc. directly rather than using a pipe to communicate with `aplay`.  These APIs will provide callbacks or blocking functions to allow you to reliably produce data at the desired sample rate (8 kHz, for example) without introducing latency.  With pipes, you will always be contending with the kernel buffer... 64 kB by default, or 2 full seconds of 16-bit stereo!  There are also simpler libraries which wrap these APIs like PortAudio (maybe your best bet?)

Answer (score 1):

To generate audio samples at 8000 Hz (or any fixed rate) you don't want your loop to "run at" that rate. That would involve huge amounts of overhead (99.99% or more) spinning doing nothing until time to generate the next sample, and (especially if you sleep rather than spinning) would be unreliable in that your process might not wake-up/get-scheduled in time for some of the samples.

Instead, you just want to be producing samples at an overall rate matching what the consumer (`aplay`/the audio device) expects. You can compute the overall current sample number you should be generating up to as something like:

```
current_time + buffer_depth - start_time
```

then, after generating up to that sample, sleep for some period proportional to the buffer depth, but sufficiently less that you won't be in trouble if your process doesn't get scheduled again right away. The buffer depth you can use depends on what kind of latency you need. If you're making sounds for live/realtime events, you probably want a buffer depth of 1/50 sec (20 ms) or less. If not, you can happily use huge buffers like 5-10 seconds.

Comment: This will cause audio glitches due to the fact that there are two clocks (audio output often runs on its own clock).

Comment: Well, kind of, but there's really no solution to that problem since OP wants to use `aplay`. For direct playback you should be be using the audio device as your time source rather than using the system clock, or otherwise the process delivering the system-clock-based (or other-clock-based) audio to the audio device (`aplay` or similar) should be doing the correction. But this IMO the whole topic is very advanced relative to OP's question/understanding and unlikely to matter until the process runs for many hours.

Comment: You say "unlikely to matter" but I routinely get clicks and pops with unsynchronized audio sources.  All it takes is `aplay` actually running at 8001 Hz instead of 8000 Hz (as measured by system clock).

Comment: Well how long it takes to matter depends on your buffering depth and the clock error. For 1s buffering it should take 8000s for that error to exhaust the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are piping data to `aplay`, you will not experience any problems with the sample rate (8 kHz, for example) because the kernel will block your program when you `write()` when the buffer is full.  This will effectively limit your audio generation to 8 kHz with no work on your part.

However, this is far from ideal.  Your application will only be throttled once the kernel buffer for the pipe is full, and the default size for pipe buffers on Linux is 64 kB.  For stereo 16-bit data at 8 kHz, this is two full seconds of audio data, so you would expect your audio to lag at least two seconds from the user input.  This is unacceptable for synthesizer applications.

The only real solution is to use the ALSA library directly (or some alternative sound API).  Using this API, you can send buffered audio data to your audio output device without accumulating excessive queued data in kernel buffers.

See [A Guide Through The Linux Sound API Jungle](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/guide-to-sound-apis) for some tips.